# IntelliJ and Local Tomcat: Mandatory?

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat7

Is it mandatory to have a local Tomcat Server in order to configure an Application Server in IntelliJ IDEA? My ultimate goal is to deploy to my remote Tomcat instance ONLY, without any local configurations.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat Application server is used as a Provided dependency to get code completion and compilation of your code that utilizes JSPs and Servlets.

Remote debug configuration needs Tomcat Application server to know the target server version and uses local server libraries to perform connection and deployment.

So, yes, it's mandatory to have a local copy installed to use Tomcat Remote debug configuration.

If you are going to debug only plain Java code without JPS, use the plain Remote debug configuration like for normal applications, it doesn't require local application server installation.